# Search tags with order in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting

I used acts_as_taggable_on gem for my Tutor model. Each tutor has multiple types of Taggings: Classes (C201, M101), Subjects (Chemistry, Math etc.) and background (Art, Science).

Students want to match with Tutor by that order. For example:

If there are 10 tutors with exact Class matched, then stop.

If there are only 5 tutors with exact Class match, then find the next 5 with Subject match.

If only 2 tutors with exact Subject match, then find the next 3 with background match.

How should I write my scope or SQL query efficiently? A naive way to do this is for each student, I have to calculate relevancy of all Tutors, and rank them accordingly. But this is way too inefficient.

Comment: What are the relations between the models?

Comment: Can you show some sample data to write the SQL query?

Comment: Thanks beck and Aayush. Please see my updated question.

Answer (score 1):

so something like Tutors.where(:class => 'value', :subject => ....).order_by(:class, :subject, ...).limit(10)

And then memorize the combinations of matches?

Answer (score 1):

Model:

```
require 'active_record'

ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Logger.new(STDERR)
ActiveRecord::Base.colorize_logging = false

ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
    :adapter => 'sqlite3',
    :dbfile  => ':memory:'
)

ActiveRecord::Schema.define do

    create_table :College do |table|
        table.column :name, :string
    end

end

class College < ActiveRecord::Base
    acts_as_taggable_on :roles, :courses, :subjects, :backgrounds
end

college = College.new(:name => 'Kerry Green', :role_list => 'student', :course_list => 'CM201', :subject_list => 'Biochemistry', :background_list = 'Science')
college.save

college = College.new(:name => 'Brian Jones', :role_list => 'student', :course_list => 'CM101', :subject_list => 'Chemistry', :background_list = 'Science')
college.save

college = College.new(:name => 'Lewis Smith', :role_list => 'student', :course_list => 'AR102', :subject_list => 'Fine Art', :background_list = 'Arts')
college.save

college = College.new(:name => 'Evan Hunt', :role_list => 'tutor', :course_list => 'CM201, CM101', :subject_list => 'Chemistry, Biochemistry', :background_list = 'Science')
college.save

college = College.new(:name => 'Stuart White', :role_list => 'tutor', :course_list => 'CM201', :subject_list => 'Biochemistry', :background_list = 'Science')
college.save

college = College.new(:name => 'Wendy Jones', :role_list => 'tutor', :course_list => 'CM201', :subject_list => 'Biochemistry', :background_list = 'Science')
college.save
```

Tag matching:

```
# find CM201 courses

@student = College.find( :name => 'Brian Jones')

@byCourse = @student.find_related_on_courses.find_tagged_with('tutor', :on=> :roles) 
 if @byCourse.length >= 10 
    // rule 1
else  
  @bySubject = @student.find_related_on_subjects.find_tagged_with('tutor', :on=> :roles) 
  if @byCourse.length >= 5 && @bySubject.length >= 5
   // rule 2
  else
     @byBackground = @student.find_related_on_backgrounds.find_tagged_with('tutor', :on=> :roles) 
     if @bySubject.length >= 2 && @byBackground.length >= 3
        // rule 3
     else
       // no match
     end
  end
end
```